# c#/winforms: How can two controls dynamically share available space?

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I setup my controls for the following situation?:

I have a parent-container for example a `GroupBox`.

Inside this parent-container I have two similar controls, like for example `ListBox`es, next to each other. They both have the same size, so the border between the two of them is exactly in the middle of the `GroupBox`.

Now when the `GroupBox` is resized, I want the `ListBox`es to also be resized, but the two should always be at the same size than the other one. So also the border between the two of them stays in the middle of the `GroupBox`.

So, how would I set up the properties for these three controls to achieve my desired behaviours?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need another container. The TableLayoutPanel is the best solution. Use 1 row and 2 columns and dock (Dock = Fill) it in the group box. The width of both columns should be set to 50%. Next you can add your controls in the individual cells and dock them (Dock = Fill)

Comment: +1 You don't *need* another container, however the table method will do the job with less code than without another container.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a `SplitContainer` with the two-halves set evenly and `IsSplitterFixed` set to `true` (to stop the user moving it):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form {
        Controls = { new SplitContainer {
            Width = 200,
            IsSplitterFixed = true,
            SplitterDistance = 100,
            SplitterWidth = 1,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Panel1 = { Controls = {
                    new ListBox {
                        IntegralHeight = false,
                        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                        BackColor = Color.Blue,
                        Items = {"abc","def","ghi"}
                    }
                }
            }, Panel2 = { Controls = {
                    new ListBox {
                        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                        BackColor = Color.Red,
                        IntegralHeight = false,
                        Items = {"jkl","mno","pqr"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    });        
}
```

Comment: thanks! yes, that might be an option. but is it also possible without an additional container?

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible without the splitcontainer.

In the resize event of the groupbox set the location of the first control to {0,0} and of the second to {GroupBox.Width/2,0}, and set the sizes of both to {GroupBox.Width/2, GroupBox.Height}

You should also leave space around the controls so they don't overlap with the border of the GroupBox.

```
private void groupBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groupBox1.SuspendLayout();

    listBox1.Location = new Point(7, 20);
    listBox2.Location = new Point(groupBox1.Width / 2, 20);

    listBox1.Size = new Size(groupBox1.Width / 2 - 6, groupBox1.Height - 27);
    listBox2.Size = new Size((groupBox1.Width + 1) / 2 - 6, groupBox1.Height - 27);

    groupBox1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Comment: You might want to set the width of the second box to (GroupBox.Width+1)/2. This makes the box one pixel wider when the group box interior width is odd, but avoids a "jumping" effect between the groupbox and the listbox border when resizing.